# Accessing a number of Indexes in a large 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have :

(i)  Array 1 - 2D numpy array of size : 50000 x 20000.

(ii)  Array 2 - Another array of zeros of similar size i.e 50000 x 20000

(iii) List 1 of indices like - [[i1,j1], [i1,j2],[i3,j3]....[in,jn]]

(iv) List 2 of indices - [[[m1,n1], [m1,n2],[m3,n3]....[m,n]]]

What would be an efficient way to do the following for each index in list 1, list 2 :

```
                       Array2[m1,n1]= array1[i1,j1]
                       Array2[m2,n2]= array1[i2,j2]
                       Array2[m3,n3]= array1[i3,j3]
                                    .
                                    .
                       Array2[mn,nn]= array1[in,jn]
```

Comment: [m1,n1] has a different value than [i1,j1].

Comment: So just assign values in the diagonal line?

Comment: `Array2[a2[:,0],a2[:,1]]= array1[a1[:,0],a1[:,1]]` with a1,a2 being the array versions of list1 and list2 respectively?

Comment: Can you please quantify what you consider "efficient"? Currently this is opinion-based.

Comment: @Divakar That worked, Thanks !

Comment: @TylerH The length of both lists is around 10^6. The code is taking around 30 minutes to execute. It would be great to reduce that time substantially. Divakar's approach brought the time down to 10 min.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you made sure the arrays sizes are identical, as well as both lists of indices, you could do simply this:

```
for N, index_couple in enumerate(list_of_indices_1):
    i = index_couple[0]
    j = index_couple[1]
    m = list_of_indices_2[N][0]
    n = list_of_indices_2[N][1]
    array2[m,n] = array1[i,j]
```

Or maybe more explicitly:

```
for N,_ in enumerate(list_of_indices_1):
    i = list_of_indices_1[N][0]
    j = list_of_indices_1[N][1]
    m = list_of_indices_2[N][0]
    n = list_of_indices_2[N][1]
    array2[m,n] = array1[i,j]
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm doing. It would be better to have a faster solution, as the len(list1) = len(list2) = 10^6